# Selenium Webdriver Python Click Doesn't Seem to be working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to login to my Wegmans account to export my orders into a spreadsheet. I'm using Selenium and chromedriver in Docker. My issue is that clicking the next button on the login/sign in page isn't having any effect on the page.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

print("Waiting for Webdriver to be available")
time.sleep(5)
print("Done waiting")

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://chrome:4444/wd/hub',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()

print("Opening Wegmans")
driver.get("https://shop.wegmans.com/login")
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Sign in'))

email = driver.find_element_by_id("signInName")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

email.send_keys("myemail@yahoo.com")
password.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_id("next").click()
driver.save_screenshot("/tmp/app/rightafterclick.png")
time.sleep(20)
driver.save_screenshot("/tmp/app/20secondsafterclick.png")
```

Both screenshots show the same thing - which is the email and password filled out but no change in the page. The 2nd screenshot should contain an error message because the email is not valid. The element id's are correct. How can I ensure that the "Sign In" button gets clicked?

Comment: looks like it is detecting selenium and the click is frozen.

Comment: Without docker, when you running it, are you getting the same issue?

Comment: Same thing is happening without docker

Comment: Just now executed your code, and observed that it clicks the next button , though doesn't do anything. Change email.send_keys("abc") and run. You will see, the validation error

Comment: I'm able to inspect the page and I see there's a 403 on POST when the button is clicked. This does not happen when I'm not using selenium.

Comment: I changed the email to abc @QualityMatters. The validation error does show up. However when using a valid email and valid password I'm getting the same 403 on POST that I just mentioned.

Comment: Yes, because the website have additional code to handle automation bots:                 Error 1020 Ray ID: 6aaed577af361b92 • 2021-11-08 12:34:09 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

Comment: When you are getting 403 service response on clicking button, it means the call is going and the click actually happened. Though the response is prevented from site. Take developer help to enable the response for your valid test credentials.

Comment: At least I didn't get my IP blacklisted. I'll probably just end up asking Wegmans to add functionality to download the orders in csv and bypass an automated solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved your problem by using below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium import webdriver


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()

print("Opening Wegmans")
driver.get("https://shop.wegmans.com/login")
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Sign in'))

time.sleep(5)

email = driver.find_element_by_id("signInName")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

email.send_keys("myemail@yahoo.com")
password.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_id("next").click()
driver.save_screenshot("rightafterclick.png")
time.sleep(20)
driver.save_screenshot("20secondsafterclick.png")
```